# Why is "be" used without a "to"

Tags: sentence-structure, subjunctives, bare-infinitives

> - His uncle had always insisted the chosen successor ***be*** solidly grounded in the Amish church.

How could the writer put ***be*** without preceding with verbs such as see, hear, watch, etc.
Why he used "be" rather than "to be"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Answer (score 4):

This is technically called "subjunctive." It's used in a subordinate clause with a *bare infinitival verb* to suggest that an idea or recommendation is necessary.

There are a few words that are usually used with the subjunctive: suggest, essential, recommend, insist etc.

The subjunctive is commonly used in American English; in British English, using the modal *should* is preferred.

Comment: In fact, [both BrE and AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insisted+he+be%2Cinsisted+that+he+be%2Cinsisted+he+should+be%2Cinsisted+that+he+should+be&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsisted%20he%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsisted%20that%20he%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsisted%20he%20should%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsisted%20that%20he%20should%20be%3B%2Cc0) favour the explicitly subjunctive form *insisted **that** he be*. But Brits prefer to include ***should*** if optional ***that*** isn't present.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Tbh, I don't really know how Ngrams works. But I believe you as a native BrE speaker.

Comment: I have a good gut feel for what people usually say/write, but terminology isn't my strong suit. You probably know more that me about that sort of thing - all I can say is my eyes glazed over a bit when I tried to figure out using this [Brief Glossary of Modality](http://dinamico2.unibg.it/anglistica/slin/modgloss.htm) whether including ***should*** axiomatically converts following ***be*** from "subjunctive" to "bare infinitive" (it's the same word, with the same meaning, so I don't really see what changes there).